# Property not set with reflection

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I've came across this strange situation. I have the following model :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(AnotherClassBase myProp)
    {
        MyProp = myProp;
    }

            private AnotherClassBase _MyProp;
    public virtual AnotherClassBase MyProp 
    {
        get
        {
            return _MyProp;
        }
        set
        {
            _MyProp = value;
            DoStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

I initially instantiate it using the constructor :

```
 var myInstance = new MyClass(new AnotherClassConcrete1());
```

And then try to change the property value with some instance of the type AnotherClassConcrete2  using this extension method :

```
public static void Set<T>(this T target, Expression<Func<T, object>> memberLamda, object value)
    {
        var memberSelectorExpression = memberLamda.Body as MemberExpression;
        if (memberSelectorExpression != null)
        {
            var property = memberSelectorExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
            if (property != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(target, value, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the debugger inspector, I can see that the value is correctly changed. However, the following returns false :

```
myInstance.MyProp is AnotherClassConcrete2
```

And the following returns true :

```
myInstance.MyProp is AnotherClassConcrete1
```

Why is that ? And how can I fix that ?

Comment: Works correctly... https://ideone.com/lA3wqj

Comment: Hum, thank you, I agree it works on your example... I'll continue to look into the specifics of my scenario to see why it doesn't work. Literally, setting the value from the constructor instead of by reflection made my code work. I really think I have included all the relevant details of my scenario... I'll continue to look into it